# Frama-C non-terminating evaluation

Tags: frama-c

I am trying to slice the following program on the printf call:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  if (argc < 3) return 1;

  int x = atoi(argv[1]);
  int y = atoi(argv[2]);

  printf("%d %d\n", x, y);

  return 0;
}
```

However, the Value Analysis plugin gives the following message:

> foo.c:9:[value] Non-termination in evaluation of function call expression argument
>           (char const *)*(argv + 2),

and the sliced program is empty! Is this a bug/feature in Frama-C? Or am I doing something wrong?

Here's a complete trace:

```
$ frama-c -slice-calls printf foo.c -then-on 'Slicing export' -print
[slicing] slicing requests in progress...
[kernel] preprocessing with "gcc -C -E -I.  foo.c"
[value] Analyzing a complete application starting at main
[value] Computing initial state
[value] Initial state computed
[value] Values of globals at initialization
foo.c:8:[kernel] warning: out of bounds read. assert \valid(argv+1);
[value] computing for function atoi <- main.
        Called from foo.c:8.
[kernel] warning: No code for function atoi, default assigns generated
[value] Done for function atoi
foo.c:9:[kernel] warning: out of bounds read. assert \valid(argv+2);
foo.c:9:[value] Non-termination in evaluation of function call expression argument
        (char const *)*(argv + 2)
[value] Recording results for main
[value] done for function main
[slicing] making slicing project 'Slicing'...
[slicing] interpreting slicing requests from the command line...
[slicing] applying all slicing requests...
[slicing] applying 0 actions...
[slicing] exporting project to 'Slicing export'...
[slicing] applying all slicing requests...
[slicing] applying 0 actions...
[sparecode] remove unused global declarations from project 'Slicing export tmp'
[sparecode] removed unused global declarations in new project 'Slicing export'
/* Generated by Frama-C */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **5.2.3 Analysis of an incomplete application** in the [value analysis manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-value-analysis.pdf):

> For a variable of a pointer type, there is no way for the analyzer to
>   guess whether the pointer should be assumed to be pointing to a single
>   element or to be pointing at the beginning of an array — or indeed, in
>   the middle of an array, which would mean that it is legal to take
>   negative offsets of this pointer. By default, a pointer type is
>   assumed to point at the beginning of an array of two elements. This
>   number can be changed with option `-context-width`. Example: if the
>   prototype for the entry point is `void main(int *t)`, the analyzer
>   assumes `t` points to an array `int S_t[2]`.

The same applies to the argument `argv` of the `main()` function of your program.
Build a proper array of pointers that you expect to correspond to `main()` arguments in practice as explained elsewhere in the manual (e.g. main_2.c page 23). If you only intend to verify or slice your program for well-formed integers in the range 0 .. 1000, you can insert `/*@ assert 0 <= x <= 1000 ; */` in the program after `x` has been assigned.

> [kernel] warning: No code for function atoi, default assigns generated

You should also read **2.3.3 Missing functions** in the same manual. Tell you what, read the manual first and try to use the value analysis and slicing plug-in later. This is a steep learning curve for a piece of software nowadays, but that is really how it is intended to be used.

Anyway, an implementation or a minimal specification should be provided for all functions that are encountered by the analyzer. The most recent release of Frama-C contains in share/libc some pretty good specifications for a lot of standard functions, which may have been installed in /usr/local/lib/Frama-C/libc on your computer.